# how arrow function works its way up its scope until it locates a value for this?

Tags: javascript

I'm reading a javascript book, below is the example with author's description:

```
let myObject = {
    greeting: "Hi, there",
    getWriter() {
        return (message) => console.log(`${this.greeting}, ${message}`);
    }
}

myObject.getWriter()("It is raining today");
```

**When the arrow function returned by getWriter is invoked, it works its way up its scope until it locates a value for this. As a consequence, the way that the getWriter function is invoked determines the value of this for the arrow function.**

I kind of get the idea but confused with the details, so`getWriter()` gets called first, then the arrow function get called, but how arrow function works it way up its scope to determines the this value to be `myObject`? I mean when `getWriter()` was called, this function's scope ended when this function finished, the arrow function shouldn't be able to know that itself was returned from getWriter function?

Answer (score 2):

Arrow functions get their `this` from the context where and when they are **evaluated**. Because your arrow function is defined within an object method, its `this` refers to the same `this` of the `getWriter()` context.

Think of it like this

```js
let myObject = {
  greeting: "Hi, there",
  getWriter () {
    let that = this // typically the myObject object though not necessarily
    let returnValue = function(message) {
      console.log(`${that.greeting}, ${message}`)
    }
    return returnValue // returns a function
  }
}

let fn = myObject.getWriter()

fn("It is raining today")
```

In the same way that `this` is captured as `that`, an arrow function captures the current `this` and binds it to itself.

---

To explain the note about what `this` is set to within `getWriter()`, consider this example

```js
myObject.getWriter.call({ greeting: 'Stay inside' })
```

Here, I'm calling `getWriter()` with a customised `this` which will be captured by the return-value function declaration within.

<sub>See [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)</sub>

Comment: `let that = this // the myObject object` need not always be true. Replacing **defined** with **executed** may be more clear.

Comment: @traktor53 I've gone with _"evaluated"_ now

Comment: @traktor53 that's a good point about `this` not always being the parent object. I've added an example to clarify

Comment: @traktor53 oh man, just noticed you also used _"evaluated"_. Didn't mean to copy, you certainly used the right term first

Answer (score 1):

It may help considering that arrow functions are expressions which capture the lexical `this` value when evaluated, for use when called some time later.

```
myObject.getWriter()("It is raining today");
```

calls `getwriter` as a method of `myObject` and by doing so causes `getwriter` to have a this value of `myObject` during execution.

```
(message) => console.log(`${this.greeting}, ${message}`)
```

When `getwriter` evaluates this expression (each and every time `getwriter` is called) it produces an arrow function object which uses the `this` value seen by `getwriter`.

So the function returned by `getwriter` uses the `this` value of the *call* to `getwriter`, which can depend on how it was called